# Diferencias al guardar datos en fichero csv en función desi el fichero existe o no empleando pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando unos datos y quería guardarlos en un fichero de extensión `.csv`. Para ello lo que hago es guardar estos en un diccionario y luego se trataría de guardarlos en el fichero `.csv`. Hago lo siguiente,

```
###### DATA ######
atleta = 'Frink'
familia = None
subfamilia = None
fecha = '03/11/2020'
code = 'SP00003'
duracion = '00:35:00'
ejers = ['Flexiones rodillas','Sentadilla profunda','Fondos en banco','Zancadas','Dominada australiana prona','Rodillas a la barra']
series = [3,3,3,3,3,3]
reps = [1,25,10,15,1,5]
reps_estaticos = None
rest_series = 90
rest_reps = 90
mark_total = None
mark_ejers = [['MD','MD','MD'],['F','J','J'],['F','F','J'],['F','J','J'],['F','F','F'],['F','F','F']]
mark_app = None
coments = None
##################


myData = {
    'Familia'   : familia,  'Sub-Familia' : subfamilia,   'Fecha' : fecha,      'Atleta': atleta,
    'Code': code,           'Duracion' : duracion,        'Ejercicios': ejers,
    'Series'    : series,   'Repeticiones'  : reps,       'Repeticiones estaticos'  : reps_estaticos,
    'Descanso series'   : rest_series,    'Descanso repeticiones' : rest_reps,
    'Evaluacion gobal WOD'  : mark_total, 'Evaluacion individual ejercicio' : mark_ejers, 'Evaluacion APP'  : mark_app,
    'Comentarios' : coments
}


# Finalmente guardamos la información en un fichero .csv
try: # Si existe fichero, añadimos los datos
    df = read_csv(myPath+'data/data.csv')
    df = df.append(myData, ignore_index=True)
except: # Si no existe, se crea.
    df = DataFrame(myData)

df.to_csv(myPath+'data/data.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Como podéis observar hago una diferenciación entre si existe o no el fichero `data.csv` en cuestión, pues si no existe habría que crearlo y si existe habría que añadir los datos al fichero ya existente. **Aquí viene el problema**, y es que en función de si realiza una o la otra acción, los datos se guardan diferentes.

Si se crea el fichero, me genera saltos de línea para guardar los datos. Concretamente estos saltos van en función del contenido de las listas. A continuación veis como queda,

[image]

En cambio si el fichero ya existe, me lo guarda todo en una misma línea (que de entrada era mi objetivo para simplificar el fichero con el mínimo de filas). A continuación podéis ver como queda.

[image]

Es decir, en conjunto la tabla ahora mismo se ve como la siguiente imagen, cuando yo de entrada quería simplemente dos líneas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que hay un parámetros que no estoy definiendo, he jugado con el `index` e `ignore_index` pero no lo consigo. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perdona es que tras leerlo varias veces, no comprendo de todo el problema, ¿Qué quieres hacer? que se te quede la linea en la que aparece todo junto, o quitar esa linea.

Comment: Buenas Alberto, pues me gustaría que indiferentemente de si se crea el documento .csv o o si ya existe, el conjunto de los datos se guarde siempre en una única línea como ya hace cuando ya existe el documento.

Comment: Gracias! Creo que ya lo he entendido, espero que mi respuesta sea lo que necesitas :). Si no lo es, no dudes en hacerme cualquier comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo con tu código yo haría los siguientes cambios:

- Cambiaría el método `.append()` por la función `concat()`
- Crear listas de listas en los datos, para que se guarden todos en la misma fila

```
import pandas as pd

myPath = "/home/rubiales/Desktop/Projects/pruebas/"

###### DATA ######
atleta = 'Frink'
familia = None
subfamilia = None
fecha = '03/11/2020'
code = 'SP00003'
duracion = '00:35:00'
ejers = [['Flexiones rodillas','Sentadilla profunda','Fondos en banco','Zancadas','Dominada australiana prona','Rodillas a la barra']]#Creamos una lista de listas para que lo ponga en una fila pandas
series = [[3,3,3,3,3,3]] #Creamos una lista de listas para que lo ponga en una fila pandas
reps =  [[1,25,10,15,1,5]] #Creamos una lista de listas para que lo ponga en una fila pandas
reps_estaticos = None
rest_series = 90
rest_reps = 90
mark_total = None
mark_ejers = [[['MD','MD','MD'],['F','J','J'],['F','F','J'],['F','J','J'],['F','F','F'],['F','F','F']]]#Creamos una lista de listas para que lo ponga en una fila pandas
mark_app = None
coments = None
##################


myData = {
    'Familia'   : familia,  'Sub-Familia' : subfamilia,   'Fecha' : fecha,      'Atleta': atleta,
    'Code': code,           'Duracion' : duracion,        'Ejercicios': ejers,
    'Series'    : series,   'Repeticiones'  : reps,       'Repeticiones estaticos'  : reps_estaticos,
    'Descanso series'   : rest_series,    'Descanso repeticiones' : rest_reps,
    'Evaluacion gobal WOD'  : mark_total, 'Evaluacion individual ejercicio' : mark_ejers, 'Evaluacion APP'  : mark_app,
    'Comentarios' : coments
}



# Finalmente guardamos la información en un fichero .csv
try: # Si existe fichero, añadimos los datos
    df = pd.read_csv(myPath+'data/data.csv')
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(myData)])

except: # Si no existe, se crea.
    df = pd.DataFrame(myData)

df.to_csv(myPath+'data/data.csv', index=None)
```

Por tanto he cambiado **la forma en la que se crean los datos** y he utilizado `pd.concat()`

### Bonus

Te he añadido la importación de pandas con el alias `pandas as pd`. Por convención suele ser así.

No sé si es tu caso, pero hay personas que en librerías como `numpy` o `pandas` se importan las funciones directamente, en vez de hacerlo con la convención del alias porque se creen que así va a ser más rápido, o se van a usar menos recursos. *Esto no es cierto, y lo único que hace es dificultar el trabajo de otros programadores o personas del equipo, **por lo que no se recomienda**

**Nota:** cuando pongo *"Esto no es cierto"* sucede por la forma en la que Python carga las librerías, tema en el que no voy a entrar, ya que no es objeto de esta pregunta.

Comment: Pues si, `from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame` porque en su momento se me dijo que esto aligeraba la ejecución... jajaj

Comment: Hemos matado dos pájaros de un tiro ;) Haré en el futuro una pregunta respuesta de porque es así, ya que se lo he visto hacer a muchas personas.

Comment: @Lleims he agregado la pregunta que prometí, por si tienes la curiosidad de saber el porque las formas de imporación no agregan ni quitan tiempo. [¿Cómo Importar las librerías de manera rápida y optimizada en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405142/c%c3%b3mo-importar-las-librer%c3%adas-de-manera-r%c3%a1pida-y-optimizada-en-python/405143#405143)