# ¿Cómo Importar las librerías de manera rápida y optimizada en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimización, python-import, eficiencia

Cuando quiero importar una librería en Python, hay distintos métodos. Yo siempre opto por los más comunes, pero cuando necesito poner el código en producción, para que vaya más rápido siempre importo directamente las funciones. Por ejemplo:

**Importaciones cuando estoy en desarrollo**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pygame.locals import *
```

**Importaciones en producción**

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame, concat
from numpy import array, zeros
```

Hago esto por dos cosas:

1. Cuando ejecuto las funciones, entiendo que la llamada es más rápida al llamar a la función
2. Importar una función al inicio es más rápido que importar todo el paquete

**¿Esto realmente hace que mi código sea más óptimo?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **¿Esto realmente hace que mi código sea más óptimo?**

**Respuesta rápida: NO**

Esto lo único que hace es que el código sea menos legible y más difícil de mantener tanto para ti como para el resto de programadores que lo usen. Además de que puede que tengas librerías con las mismas funciones y una sobrescriba a la otra dando problemas. **Lo que se debe de hacer es seguir las convenciones del lenguaje y de cada biblioteca.**

Vamos a entrar en detalle, para ello debemos conocer como realiza Python las importaciones.

## ¿Cómo importa Python?

**Resumiendo** cuando Python importa las librerías hace las siguientes operaciones:

1. Va al cache y busca si el módulo ha sido previamente importado, si ya ha sido importado lo coge del cache, si no pasa a la siguiente operación. Nosotros podemos ver el cache con `sys.modules`
2. Va a `sys.path` y busca el módulo, si no lo encuentra dará un `ModuleNotFoundError`, si lo encuentra pasa a la siguiente operación. (Esta es la parte más compleja de la importación, pero para centrarnos en la pregunta vamos a quedarlo así resumido)
3. Lee el código del módulo y crea un objeto tipo `types.ModuleType`.
4. Cargar el archivo del módulo en memoria.
5. Añade una entrada a `sys.module` con el nombre como **clave** y donde se encuentra el módulo (lo agrega al cache).
6. Compila y ejecuta el código y tendríamos una referencia en nuestro `globals()` para poder usarlo.

Es importante recalcar, que cuando el módulo es importado por primera vez, **todo el código del módulo es ejecutado** y esto **solo se hace una vez** y se queda **cargado en memoria**, no cada vez que se ejecuta la función.

Python a diferencia de otros lenguajes realiza las importaciones **cuando se lanza el código** (at run time) esto es diferente de por ejemplo C, C++... donde los módulos son compilados y enlazados en el momento de la compilación.

Con esto ya se deduce que **no hay ninguna optimización de tiempo ni espacio**, ya que aunque importes una función, Python siempre va a compilar y ejecutar el módulo de la misma forma y lo queda cargado. Pero vamos a ver entonces en que cambian las distintas formas de importar

## Formas de importar

Vamos a resumir todo lo anterior como el proceso de carga, por lo que sucedería lo siguiente en las distintas formas:

### Importando el módulo

`import math`

1. Cargamos el módulo `math` en memoria si no se encontraba previamente cargado.
2. Añadimos la referencia a `sys.modules` con la clave `math`
3. añadimos el símbolo del mismo nombre `math` a nuestro `namespace` referenciando al objeto `math` de `sys.modules` por lo que podremos llamar cualquier función de esta biblioteca con `math.`

### Creando un alias para el módulo

`import math as py_math`

1. Cargamos el módulo `math` en memoria si no se encontraba previamente cargado.
2. Añadimos la referencia a `sys.modules` con la clave `math`
3. añadimos el símbolo  `py_math` a nuestro `namespace` referenciando al objeto `math` de `sys.modules` por lo que podremos llamar cualquier función de esta biblioteca con `py_math.`

### Importando una función de un módulo

`import math import sin` (esta es la más polémica a la hora de creer que es más eficiente)

1. Cargamos el módulo `math` en memoria si no se encontraba previamente cargado.
2. Añadimos la referencia a `sys.modules` con la clave `math`
3. añadimos el símbolo  `sin` a nuestro `namespace` referenciando al objeto `math.sin` de `sys.modules`, por lo que cuando ejecutemos `sin` python llamará a `math.sin`
4. NO tenemos `math` en nuestro `namespace`, por lo que no podremos usar el resto de sus funciones.

### Importando todas las funciones del módulo

`from math import *`

1. Cargamos el módulo `math` en memoria si no se encontraba previamente cargado.
2. Añadimos la referencia a `sys.modules` con la clave `math`.
3. Añadimos todos los símbolos que se encuentran en `math` (y que nos permite) a nuestro `namespace`.
4. NO tenemos `math` en nuestro `namespace`.

Como podemos ver Python siempre realiza las mismas operaciones a excepción de como pone la/s referencia/s en nuestro `namespace`. Es decir **lo único que cambia es como tu llamas a ese paquete, o como llamas a la función.** (esto conlleva como vemos más adelante, cambios de tiempo pero son irrisorios y sin importancia) Nada más.

En ningún caso estás "importando parcialmente el paquete" o "importar el paquete cada vez que llamas a la función" ni nada por el estilo.

## Comparación de tiempos

Vamos ver la comparación de tiempos, tanto en el momento de importar módulos, como de ejecutar funciones.

### Importación de módulos

Vamos a comprobar como todo lo anterior es cierto, (o parcialmente cierto) ejecutando código. Para ello vamos ha crear distintas importaciones y vamos a ejecutarlas 10M de veces, 5 repeticiones:

```
import timeit


def math_import():
    import math

def math_import_func():
    from math import sin

def math_import_alias():
    import math as py_math

print("Importar el módulo: ", timeit.repeat("math_import()", "from __main__ import math_import", repeat=5, number=10_000_000))
print("Importar una función: ", timeit.repeat("math_import_func()", "from __main__ import math_import_func", repeat=5, number=10_000_000))
print("Importar módulo con alias: ", timeit.repeat("math_import_alias()", "from __main__ import math_import_alias", repeat=5, number=10_000_000))
```

**Salida:**

```
Importar el módulo:  [1.4988863739999942, 1.4830362890024844, 1.4795733890023257, 1.4750298549988656, 1.4765737379966595]
Importar una función:  [7.225122679999913, 7.060959832000663, 7.142371303998516, 7.129539630001091, 7.128482500000246]
Importar módulo con alias:  [1.4638380440010224, 1.4583061759985867, 1.4683159539999906, 1.4613551369984634, 1.4618487959996855]
```

Importar un módulo con alias o sin alias, da exactamente lo mismo. Pero al contrario de lo que nos podría decir la intuición **importar una función directamente, es 5 veces más lento** que importar el módulo completo.

Esto sucede porque la importación del módulo completo, lo que hace es coger directamente todo el módulo y ponerlo en nuestro `namespace`, mientras que la importación de una función necesita cargar el módulo completo al igual que antes, **pero después tiene que buscar la función dentro del módulo**, para traer a nuestro namespace solo la función. Este paso extra es lo que crea el aumento de tiempo.

### Uso de funciones

Vamos a ver ahora como será el uso de funciones, si es más rápido realizar `math.sin(2)` o importar primero dicha función y después ejecutar `sin(2)`

```
import timeit
import math

def math_usar_modulo():
    math.sin(2)

from math import sin
def math_usar_funcion():
    sin(2)

print("Usar funciones con módulo: ", timeit.repeat("math_usar_modulo()", "from __main__ import math_usar_modulo", repeat=5, number=10_000_000))
print("Usar directamente la función: ", timeit.repeat("math_usar_funcion()", "from __main__ import math_usar_funcion", repeat=5, number=10_000_000))
```

**Salida:**

```
Usar funciones con módulo:  [1.350086618000205, 1.3652590480014624, 1.408665970000584, 1.3901464710033906, 1.39300650199948]
Usar directamente la función:  [1.0757436029998644, 1.0714291420008522, 1.0663878439991095, 1.0607737700011057, 1.0583900019992143]
```

Usar directamente la función `sin(2)` es un 30% más rápido que con el módulo `math.sin(2)`. Esto tiene sentido, ya que nos sucede lo contrario que en la importación.

Al tener la función en el `namespace` solo tiene que cogerla y ejecutarla, mientras que cuando la llamamos al módulo, Python tienen el módulo en el namespace y dentro tiene que buscar la función `sin()`

## Conclusiones

Llegado aquí puede que te hayas hecho un lío. Primero he dicho que todo era igual, y después he demostrado que no es igual. Lo realmente pesado, que es cargar el módulo en memoria, siempre lo hace igual, **hagas lo que hagas siempre va a cargar todo el módulo en memoria** (nada de importaciones parciales, o compilar solo una función). Lo único que añade o quita tiempo es la diferencia de búsqueda que hace Python internamente mediante diccionarios, y los diccionarios de Python son muy muy rápidos.

Piensa en las pruebas, ¿10M de importaciones? ¿Quién realiza 10M de importaciones?. Usar 10M de veces una función para obtener un rendimiento de menos de 30 centésimas de segundo, es ridículo.

La conclusión que debemos sacar, es que Python tiene una manera uniforme y realmente optimizada de trabajar con los módulos.

Lo que se debe de hacer como indiqué al principio **es seguir las convenciones que existen en el lenguaje y en las distintas bibliotecas**, ya que si no se hace, lo único que se consigue es que el código sea menos legible, más difícil de mantener y entender por ti mismo, y por otros programadores.