# ImportError: cannot import name 'date' from partially initialized module 'datetime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importación

Por ejemplo escribo el siguiente código:

```
from datetime import date, time

print("fecha actual: ", date.today())
```

Me da como resultado:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'date' from partially initialized module 'datetime' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: A mi me funciona. Debe haber algo más. ¿Publicaste el código completo?

Comment: También puede ser porque hay archivo con el nombre **datetime.py**

Answer (score 0):

Como indica Leonardo en los comentarios lo que sucede es que has nombrado dentro del mismo fichero un archivo (posiblemente el mismo en el que estás) con el nombre `datetime.py`. Por ello te da el error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'date' from partially initialized module 'datetime' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Esto se debe en que Python a la hora de realizar las importaciones, busca el módulo a importar de la siguiente manera.

1. Primero busca el módulo en la cache, para ver si ya ha sido importado. Si ya ha sido importado lo coge de la cache. Podemos ver lo que Python tiene en la cache con `sys.modules`
2. Segundo va a `sys.path` y busca el módulo, si el módulo se encuentra ahí lo importa (este es tu caso). Si no se encuentra da un error de importación.

Ahora **vamos a tu caso que es el segundo**:

Si ejecutamos:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

Esto nos da todas las rutas donde Python busca tus modulos, **Siempre la primera ruta, sera el directorio donde se encuentra el fichero que estás ejecuntando**. Nunca va a ser el sitio donde tienes instalado los paquetes. Por lo que si en el directorio donde estás ejecutando tu programa tienes un archivo con el nombre de un paquete, **tratará de importar ese fichero, en vez de el módulo que se encuentra instalado**. Y a esto se debe tu error.

Si quieres saber más sobre la importación de librerías, puedes ver esta otra pregunta del sitio [¿Cómo Importar las librerías de manera rápida y optimizada en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405142/c%c3%b3mo-importar-las-librer%c3%adas-de-manera-r%c3%a1pida-y-optimizada-en-python)

Comment: En realidad, ahora la [importación de módulos](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/import.html) es algo más sofisticada, con una búsqueda previa de cargadores de módulos en `sys.meta_path`. Puede ser incluso que el módulo no exista como fichero o que forme parte de un fichero zip. Lo correcto sería usar `importlib.util.find_spec` para saber de dónde sale un módulo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ChemaCortes por la información, voy a leer bien la documentación y en cuanto pueda mejoro la respuesta :)